# Navicat export large table in multiple files

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, navicat

I'm using Navicat to connect to a remote MySQL server and I want to 
transfer 1 or more large tables (sizes are ~3-4 GB) into my local environmet.

For my local environment I'm using phpMyAdmin and I can't import 
tables as large as that (even after changing configuration values in the .ini file)

How can I dump a table into multiple files using Navicat?
I searched on the official site and went trough the options but had no luck.

Is this just not possible? 
If so, I'd apreciate any suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import, the [phpMyAdmin manual](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems) has some ideas:

- Look at the [`$cfg['UploadDir']`](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) feature. This allows one to upload a file to the server via scp, ftp, or your favorite file transfer method. PhpMyAdmin is then able to import the files from the temporary directory.
- Using a utility (such as BigDump) to split the files before uploading.
- Use the MySQL command line client to import the files directly. You can do this by issuing the “source” command from within MySQL: `source filename.sql;`